# Can't install Node.js plugin on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have installed [this](http://nodejsdb.org/db-mysql/) database plugin for Node.js called 'db-mysql' and I've gone through all the steps mentioned on the site without getting errors, which must mean that the plugin is installed. But when I run my .js file (given below) in the Apache server I get this error.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'db-mysql'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
at require (module.js:378:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/server.js:4:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

Here is the sample code I'm running.

```
var http = require("http");
var mysql = require("db-mysql");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");

//Database Connectivity//
  new mysql.Database({
    hostname: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'test'
}).on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
}).on('ready', function(server) {
    console.log('Connected to ' + server.hostname + ' (' + server.version + ')');
}).connect();
///////////////////////

  response.end();
}).listen(8889);
```

Did I miss anything during installation?

Answer (score 3):

If you install module like in example

```
npm install db-mysql
```

Node will search it here

```
./project_root/node_modules/db-mysql
```

So make sure this path is correct in your case.
Other option is to install it globally by using -g flag

```
npm install db-mysql -g
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a sym link that points to where your modules are physically installed
Name this link node_modules and put it inside the folder of your project